# return to base class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I have a code in my base module:

```
  class start_Game(object):
        def __init__(self):
            print "You landed on planet and see three rooms."
            print "You need to choose one room to enter"
            self.door=raw_input("Pick number of door (1,2 or 3)>>>")
            try:
                assert(int(self.door)>0 and int(self.door)<=3)
                self.password=('%d%d%d')%(randint(1,9),randint(1,9),randint(1,9))
                print self.password
                self.ROOMs={'1':Medical_room,'2':Library,'3':basement,'4':End}
                while True:
#                break
                   room=self.ROOMs[self.door]
#                print room()
                   if self.door=='1':
                      self.door=room().play(self.password)
                   else:
                      self.door=room().play()
```

This way I want to run basement module entering 3 number. My basement module is:

```
from End import *

class basement(object):
     def __init__(self):
        print"You enterd dark room and something makes noise"
     def play(self):
        choice=raw_input("Do you want to continue?y/n")
        if choice=='y':
            End().play()
        else:
            start_Game()???
```

My question is how can I return to start_game class and start my game fron the beggining?

Comment: Please forgive me if I am wrong but it looks like based on what I can see from this code, that you don't have a proper understanding of what classes are and what they do and how/when to use them. May I suggest just using functions for what you are trying to do.

Comment: No. I do task from Zet Shaw book. And there I must use modules and classes. So if you can please advice what can i do here. Also I am newbie to python so can have some misunderstandings with classes)))

Comment: I suggest you master your basics before trying to make something like a game. Classes are especially advanced. May I recommend this amazing book? http://briggs.net.nz/snake-wrangling-for-kids.html It will teach you how to code in python in a fun and informative way, and it's 100% free.

Answer (score 0):

i may be misunderstanding, but perhaps all you need is to add the following to your base module:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_Game()
```

and then run the base module with python: `python my_module.py`

the `if __name__ == '__main__':` is true only when you are running the module.  when it is true it creates the game.

although, as others have said, the way that you are using the classes is unusual.